# Error NU5129: - At least one .targets file was found, but 'build/xyz.targets' was not

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, nuget, target

VS2022, .Net 6.0, Asp.Net - WebAPI.

After a few changes to project files we're seeing this error reported in the build when we publish to Nuget.

```
NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error NU5129: - At least one .targets file was found in 'build/', but 'build/Company.Base.Core.targets' was not.
```

We are reviewing the changes but nothing sticks out, we can't reproduce it locally.

```
<Content Include="Company.Base.Core.targets">
  <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
  <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
  <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
```

After deleting the .targets file and building it gets regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

There was two things we thought could have caused the problem:

```
 1. <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
 2. <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Company.Base.Core.Tests" />
```

My gut feeling was the first and when I went to find all instances of `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` to comment them out, I noticed in the Company.Base.Core.targets file it already existed.

Deleteing/commenting out `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` from all project files and leaving it in the .targets file resolved the issue.